# Disabling a popup

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to Disable a popup which keeps showing up, which is a "Chrome Extension".

I am attaching a screenshot and also the code.

[image]

What I am trying to do is I want to click the Disable button.

The code I am using is:

```
 public static void Initialize()
 {
 //Instance = new FirefoxDriver(); 
 //Instance = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Sele2"); 
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
 var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 Instance = new ChromeDriver(basePath, options);
 Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    }
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with --disable-extensions
Take a look here [chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-on-automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-on-automation)

Comment: Thank you @lauda :) It helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more arguments as `--disable-extensions` in your chrome options as below :-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking","--disable-extensions");
var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 Instance = new ChromeDriver(basePath, options);
  Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```