# How to handle Ad On's in selenium with C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, specflow, browser-addons

Whenever I am running my automation test script using Spec-flow & `Selenium` with `C#`, there is a ad on popup on `GoogleChrome` whose screenshot I am attaching below, I want dismiss the pop up and make sure it doesn't show up during execution.

How Can I do that.? Please explain detail

[image: https]

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss this popup, you should add arguments as `--disable-extensions` in your `ChromeOptions` during initialization of `ChromeDriver` as below :-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I used your above code, but its still showing that pop-up :(
Do i need to give anything else in place of "--disable-extensions" ??

Comment: But it is working in my case, you can see this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-on-selenium-webdriver-au

Answer (score 0):

To *dismiss* the  pop up, you can do something as simple as clicking on the body of the page, when running your tests.

If you don't want to see it at all during test execution, then perhaps you should follow the posted answer about disabling extensions.