# when I'm running my automation tests,I keep getting the "Disable Developer Mode Extension" in mobile emulation,I am using Chrome 2.21 driver

Tags: selenium

Here is the Sample code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

//this line of code added to disable extension but still getting the alert               capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

How to disable this extension alert in mobile emulation mode?

If I add the below code,mobile emulation is not showing:

ChromeOptions options=  new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

How to disable this alert in mobile emulation mode using Selenium webdriver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ChromeDriver - Disable developer mode extensions pop up on Selenium WebDriver automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-on-selenium-webdriver-au)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ChromeOptions chop =  new ChromeOptions();
chop.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chop);
```