# Webdriver starts with no extensions visible except one

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I try to load a script in Eclipse, the chrome gets opened, but extensions are not visible except `C`. I don't what is that, usually there are a lot of extensions. How can I bring those upfront when testing?

[image]

This code didn't help. Gets started, but still extensions are not visible, again, only `C` is visible that I don't know what it is:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--enable-extensions");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: This has nothing with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-on-selenium-webdriver-au

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by packaging the extension and adding to `options`:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File("chrome-extensions.crx"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```