# keep "Disable developer mode" closed while adding extension

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. In order to prevent the download bar in Chrome I use:

```
options.addExtensions(new File("Upload\\Disable-Download-Bar_v1.5.crx"));
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

which works fine. The only issue is that at the start of the test it opens a popup window

[image]

I used

```
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
```

to keep it closed but of course it prevented the extension and I had the download bar back. So how can I add the extension but keep this popup window closed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087724/chromedriver-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-on-selenium-webdriver-au?rq=1 Does this answer it for you?

Comment: no he as I said they are using `"--disable-extensions"` which halts the extension, but i want to have it without this popup