# ChromeDriver C# Disable developer extensions selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to disable extensions when running selenium in my C# project. Using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23229927/4896260), I was able to do so.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
var drv = new ChromeDriver("MY_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH", options);
```

However, this doesn't work with the latest version of Chrome v63 and the [selenium webdriver v2.9](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/). After doing some research, I found that the driver includes an automation extension which is still enabled, when the disable extensions argument is passed. The [suggestion](https://github.com/lefthandedgoat/canopy/issues/376) used below does not work with the .NET driver.

`chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);`

As I have a managed machine and I can't enable the access to install Chrome extensions. How do I disable all extensions along with the automation extension in C#?

Comment: Given that the .NET equivalent of `setExperimentalOption` is `AddAdditionalCapability`, I would expect it to work, as long as one uses the right method. However, chromedriver 2.9 is ancient, and nowhere near a recent version, so you should probably update that to the latest of 2.35.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to JimEvans, I was able to find a solution by updating to the [latest driver v2.35](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/) and adding the additional capability as follows:

```
options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

*Additionally, if one wants to the automation infobar, the can use the following:*

```
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
```

Comment: AddAdditionalCapability is obsolete with Selenium 4. Use AddAdditionalOption.