# Turn off notification of chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to install this extension *silently* . I know how to install this silently but I get chrome notifications like: `Disable developer mode extensions!`

My path of installing the extension to chrome silent is add string:
`--load-extension="C:\Program Files\..\ --no-first-run`
to target of chrome shortcut.

- How can I turn off this notification silently?
- Is there any alternate way of installing chrome extension silently?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is *shady*, even if you have the best of intentions.

Chrome developers have hardened Chrome against malware, and you see the results of that work.

1) [Developer extension popup cannot be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up/). I quote the Chrome bug tracker on the feature request to make a setting: [*"Sorry, we know it is annoying, but you the malware writers..."*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337734)

2) Silently installing an extension bypassing Chrome security mechanisms is blocked by securely signed preference files of Chrome. If you just add an extension where extensions normally are, it will not be enabled.

3) Actually interacting with Chrome to install an extension out-of-band is possible, but it's not going to be silent. Only for extensions in Chrome Web Store, you [can modify the registry and let Chrome install it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry) on next start-up. However, the user will receive a popup stating that an extension was installed by a third party, and offering to disable it. Once disabled, you cannot attempt it again (it will be locally blacklisted).

4) The only truly silent method is available to enterprise users. For computers that are part of a domain, the administrator of the domain can silently [force-install extensions through domain policy](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist). The user will not be able to disable the extension. However, **this only works for domains**.

Comment: Hi, I have the best of intentions: i have a software using Native Messaging technology, to use this software the user must use an extension and not all user can install an extension. So, i want to install an extension when user run install my software.

Comment: 4) The only truly silent method is available to enterprise users. For computers that are part of a domain, the administrator of the domain can silently force-install extensions through domain policy. The user will not be able to disable the extension. However, this only works for domains.=> I dont understand:  who's enterprise users and what's "this only works for domains"? Can you explain it? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Developer extension popup cannot be disabled. I quote the Chrome bug tracker on the feature request to make a setting: "Sorry, we know it is annoying, but you the malware writers..."
=> Can you tell me when this notification appear? it's alway appear except extension installed from chrome web store?

Comment: It appears on every Chrome start if there is an "unpacked" extension installed. `--load-extension` is loading an extension as unpacked.

Comment: Thank you very much Xan!

Comment: Hi @Xan, can you explain me what's an "unpacked" extension? when i install extension from chrome web store an extension stored in: "AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\" why this not an "unpacked" extension?

Comment: Because you installed it as a .crx _package_ from the Store. Please note that Chrome [will block packed extensions not from the Store](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Write a Script to open a new window as soon as chrome is opened and then close the old window.

Add the following code to your background java script file.

```
chrome.windows.create({type: 'normal',focused: true, state: 'maximized'}, function(window) {
                 chrome.windows.getAll( function(windows)
                 {
                     for(var i=0;i<windows.length;i++)
                     {
                         if(windows[i].id!=window.id)
                         {
                             chrome.windows.remove(windows[i].id);
                         }
                     }

                 });
             } );
```

Note: To work as expected, after adding/installing the extension to chrome, **restart** chrome manually