# Disable developer mode extensions error in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Java Selenium. I came across the following error:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gezinomi.com/");
```

Picture of error:

[image]

Comment: That error message is not in English so you will have to translate it since this is an English-only site.

Comment: Sorry. I update the image.
http://i.hizliresim.com/2nN9NN.png

Comment: This is not an error, it's a message. It shouldn't affect your tests. I"m guessing you have a custom profile that you are loading because Chrome should be clean otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is [not an error](http://techdows.com/2013/12/chrome-disable-developer-mode-extensions.html), since if you click `Cancel` option, it'll just follow the path normally.

However, it is probably causing the test to fail, once the browser remains waiting the confirmation. You can disable it through Selenium Java code, as already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up/23132321#23132321):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.gezinomi.com/");
```

Comment: I did what you said, but I met this kind of problem.Shown here:  Unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors"
http://i.hizliresim.com/r68271.jpg

Comment: That's strange. I tested here and it's working fine. Which version of selenium chromedriver are you using? I'm using 2.25.XXX

Comment: I'm using the latest version. 2.9 (https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Comment: Version 2.9 is not the latest one, we're already at 2.26. Please, update to at least 2.25 and try again.

Comment: Thank you :). Fixed it when using version 2.26. Does not it happen on other versions of this link? (Chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Example 2.9

Comment: Probably it does. Each version of the driver refers to a specific Chrome browser upgrade, to add/update/remove features as the releases go. The point is, version 2.9 is too old (2014), so always use the latest version to evict problems like that. :)

Comment: @ÖmerÇelik, also, don't forget voting up and checking the answer as right. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.I'm taking the warning.I cannot vote.:(

Comment: Yes, but you always can mark an answer as right for your questions, apart of your reputation..

Answer (score 0):

That popup was problematic while running tests remotely on SauceLabs. I tried the ChromeOptions argument `"--disable-extensions"` which didn't work. I gave up, accepting that a chunk of screen would not be visible.

As soon as I stopped researching, I came across [this reference](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) which clearly defines the Chrome option as `"--disable-extensions-file-access-check"`.

I don't know why this was so hard to find, but hopefully it can help others waste LESS of their time.