# How to modify an installed extension on Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

An extension I used a lot changed developers and the new versions, even though they have some bugfixes, have annoying scammy advertisements. I managed to remove them by downloading the .CRX file, extracting it, editing the code (simple HTML) and then adding it to the browser using "Load unpacked extension". Problem is, every time I launched Chrome, there was an annoying pop-up telling me that developer mode was on and that I had to disable it. I tried the .BAT file that was supposed to edit some .DLL and stop the pop-up, but it didn't work. What are my alternatives? How can I edit an extension that I've installed through the store?

EDIT: I found the assets on my PC, problem is, every time I remove the pictures, Chrome automatically downloads them again. How can I disable that?

Comment: That is the only way.

Comment: It sounds like you already edited the extension. The problem you are complaining about appears to be the *single* popup that you only have to dismiss once every time you start Chrome. What you have basically said is: "I've already edited something. How do I edit it?"  Please clarify your question

Comment: My question is, how to edit an extension that is INSTALLED through the store, not downloaded from a third party site and unzipped. Using Developer mode, I was able to remove the adverts, but I can't apply the changes.

Comment: there is no difference between a modified store extension and a 3rd party extension, both are deemed unsafe. else just pasting the 3rd party extension into a store extension would prevent the protection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable developer mode extensions pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up)