# Modify chrome extension for personal use

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to modify a chrome extension for personal use. However, I have not been able to install it satisfactorily.

When I use 'load unpacked extension', my browser warns me every time I launch that I am using developer mode extensions. If I pack it and install it, I get the error 'this extension may have been corrupted' and cannot enable it.

I have tried removing the 'key' from the manifest.json and updating the version number, but still get the corruption error. What do I need to do to prevent this error from coming up?

Edit: I tried hosting it on the Chrome Web Store under private visibility, but when I try to install it I get 'An error has occurred: Access denied'.

Comment: You try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome ?

Comment: Did you delete the `_metadata` folder in your modified copy? If you haven't, try that before packing and installing it.

Comment: If you don't remove the _metadata folder, you get an error. I removed it.

Comment: @OriEng I took a look at that. I don't have Windows 10 Home, so I can't use Group Policy.

Comment: [How to hack chrome.dll to get rid of the "disable developer mode extensions" pop up](//stackoverflow.com/a/30361260)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, that helped, but I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Comment: Well there's none so far, see https://crbug.com/491689