# Self-signed crx displayed as corrupted in Google Chrome 63

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Looks like starting from the Google Chrome 63 loading self-signed crx file fails with a message: "This extension may have been corrupted". 
From the browser logs I see that Chrome is trying to check the verified contents from the store, and, of course, failing.

```
content_hash_fetcher.cc(252)] Missing verified contents for cfbklnofppkbgcfhppceodfodekoecoa, fetching...
job failed for cfbklnofppkbgcfhppceodfodekoecoa reason:1
VerifyFailed cfbklnofppkbgcfhppceodfodekoecoa reason:1
```

That's happening for all extensions I can check.
Self-signed crx were disabled on reloading Chrome for a while now, but that was mostly OK for basic testing. Now it seems to be not possible at all. 
Is there a way to install extensions for testing on Chrome 63?

Installing unpacked extensions works (for now), but that's not the same as installing crx. We had some issues which were not happening with unpacked extensions, mostly with init and storages.

UPD: the issue is tracked here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794219

Comment: You may want to refer with this [thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854) if you are having an issue with Self signed certificate. It also might be possible to take ssl/server.pem add run it through https://certificatetools.com/, then add an subjectAltName=DNS:localhost.

Comment: @abielita Thank you. This pkey is generated by Chrome and was working prior to 63, so it seems to be not the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure exactly why this is happening, but the "fix" for us was to put a dummy `update_url` key in the `manifest.json` for the extension:

```
"update_url": "https://www.google.com"
```

Any old URL will do.

**Warning:** You will need to remove this before deploying to the Chrome Web Store as it might break your users' upgrade process.

**Chrome bug** this is the chrome bug tracking this issue. Please star it so that it gets some attention https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794219

Also not sure if this will continue to work in the future.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to do something - extension is no longer 'corrupted', but it gets disabled immediately and it's not possible to enable it back.  
Do you use any special configs? And what's your browser version?

Comment: @AnatolySazanov On Mac it's fine for me. On Windows, our testers need to add a special Registry Key to whitelist the extension ID. But they always had to do that: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/google_chrome_v24_windows/2013-02-21/finding/V-35623

Comment: this workaround works on chrome canary 65, and chrome stable 62, 63

Comment: @Anatoly Sazanov Re. whitelisting extensions, this may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38011386/1754517 (I'm using this method to whitelist an off-store extension I wrote)

Comment: @Jimadine thank you. Unfortunately, we cannot use GPO method right now.