# How do I remove "disable developer mode extensions" message in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I recently added a customized extension into Google Chrome and every time I open Chrome I receive this message. Is there any way to disable this message?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPZzE.png)

Comment: Seems like it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable developer mode extensions pop up in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up-in-chrome)