# Using custom Chrome extension without developer mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have custom extensions that I coded\edited and of course, can only install in developer mode.
I don't mind being in developer mode except that there is one major issue.

If for any reason the developer mode gets turned off and on again, the extension does not come back.

Ok, so what's wrong? Just import it again, right?

Well, when I import it again, all of my custom settings in the extension are gone.

For instance, I customized an "Extension Manager" extension that allows you to create extension groups.
If developer mode is turned off and on and the extension is reimported, all of my custom groups are gone.

Yes, I have the ability to export my settings to import again but it's a hassle.

Is there a way to have an extension that was installed in developer mode come back with all it's settings, even if developer mode was turned off and on again?

Or a way to LOCK the developer mode so it's always on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not delete extensions when the developer mode is disabled. If it does for you then it's a bug and should be reported on [crbug.com](https://crbug.com). However you probably used an incorrect method to modify an existing installed extension. You should copy it in another directory first outside of the browser profile. Then delete `_metadata` directory inside and install the extension from this new directory. It will replace the old extension from the web store because the id will be the same.  Its data will be kept. The id is pinned by the `"key"` entry in manifest.json of an installed extension.

Other notes:

1. You can switch to a non-stable Chrome channel (or Chromium or even a fork like Kinza) which doesn't warn about developer mode extensions, note this is a Windows-specific behavior in Chrome stable, not present in Linux or MacOS.
2. See how to install CRX in stable Chrome via policies (no need for dev mode): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38011386).
3. Use a backup script or tool that archives your browser profile directories where the settings are stored (`Local Storage`, `*Settings`) and puts them into a separate files per each day for like the last week.

Comment: I did use an external folder and deleted the metadata directory. I will look into the bug option. I don't want to switch the Chrome flavour. I backup my profile folders via Syncovery. I can also pull them out of the Macrium Reflect images that I create weekly.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug. Cleared cache and did a weekly computer restart and loaded extension stays even after disabling developer mode. Thanks.